# Need help understanding spline and basis function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, spline

[image: img]

I am reading chapter 5 of *The Elements of Statistical Learning* by Hastie et al.  I would like to ask:

1. Are the two knots positioned at the two red circles in the top left panel?
2. What is the purpose of $h_1(X) = 1$?
3. What is the purpose of $h_2(X) = X$?
4. Why do we only have $K$ basis functions?  For instance with 2 knots, dont we need 3 equations (one for each interval)?
5. Can I have an explanation for equation $(5.5)$?

Thank you so much!

Comment: This is one of the worst explanations of splines I’ve ever seen. I’ve been working in this area for more than four decades, and I don’t understand what the text is trying to say. I’m not surprised that you got no answers. But the answer to your question #1 is “yes”.